# AWS SAM, reference function name in Globals section

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, sam

I'm using a yaml AWS SAM file for CI/CD purposes.I need to add a new tag with the functionName as a value for that tag in each lambda function in that file.

Is it possible to do this without the need to define that tag separately in each function, knowing that I already have a functionName property already set for each lambda?

So Instead of this

```
 Resources:
  Function1:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: function1
      Tags:
        MyTag: function1         # << check this
  Function2:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: function2
      Tags:
        MyTag: function2        #  << check this
```

Im wondering if I can do this:

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Tags:
      MyTag: <FunctionName> # << reference to function name

Resources:
  Function1:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: function1
  Function2:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: function2
```

Comment: No, this is not possible as far I know. You'll have to define a common global tag or use function specific tag in the `sam` template. But why would you want to have a seperate tag for each function anyways? That totally defeats the purpose of tags. Tags are usually used to group lambdas of a similar type together so that it's easier to filter and view them by tag in the lambda console.

Answer (score 0):

> Two ways to do this, check which one works for you

1. Using reference for instance in your case if you want to refer "Function1" you should use Ref: "Function1" or Ref: "Function1LambdaFunction" (incase its defined using function tag)
2. Get Attribute function - for instance in your case it would be (you can replace "Function1" to "Function1LambdaFunction" if you are using a direct function tag

```
    - Fn::GetAtt: [Function1, FunctionName]
```

Comment: but then Function2 will have Function1 as MyTag value which I dont want.
every function must have its own name.

Comment: I don't think this will work. As per [SAM template anatomy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html), the only attribute available for reading is the `Arn`.

Comment: @salvino updated its "FunctionName"

Comment: @xMemz if you want to have own name then it might create a circular dependency so optimal solution will be to create environment variable and pass in both places something like
environment:
    Function1Name: "function1"
then
${self:provider.environment.Function1Name} at both places

Comment: @AsfarIrshad as much as I wish `FunctionName` to work, it doesn't really work. I tried it in SAM template file. I think its because the only property available for reading via `GetAttr` is the function `Arn` value.